# How to Pause Image Slider control

Tags: jssor, onpause

I did a search for pause and came up with this [How to Pause Sliding on Click Event in jssor slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757753/how-to-pause-sliding-on-click-event-in-jssor-slider)

not answered.

I have a few slider containers.  Based on a button click I am hiding or showing the specific Slider container.  Thing is when they are hidden or not shown the slide show is still occurring...taking up unnecessary resources.
What I want to do is when the user clicks a button and shows Container 1 I want to manually pause Container 2 and 3.

Any thoughts?

I am using the simple fade slideshow here: http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider.html

Answer (score 2):

Got it with this

jssor_slider4.$Play();

jssor_slider1.$Pause();